# Align Logo and navigation button inline centered HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, vertical-alignment

Hi i have the following problem,
I have this navigation bar ([image: SEE IMAGE])

and i want to have the logo of the app (currently "AppName") inline with the hamburger menu on the left. so without the weird blank space on top. Any ideas?

EDIT:
this is how it needs to be (from adobe XD)
[image]

My code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AppName</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <span onclick="openMenu()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
        <h1 class="logo">AppName</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');

*{
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav{
    background-color: #0A0E44;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.fas{
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.logo{ 
    *display: flex;(Tried this does not work)
    align-items: center; (Tried this does not work)
    justify-content: center;* (Tried this does not work)
}

.navbar{
    *display: inline;* (Tried this does not work)

}
```

Please help me!

BeldrNl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I added `display:inline;` to my logo and changed the `margin-left` to `40%` and that did it.

Thanks!

CSS:

```css
display: inline;
margin-left: 40%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mess around with these values:

```
.logo {
  width: 60%;
}

.nav {
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Does not work so well. keeps having the hamburger menu and the logo on two seperate horizontal lines. i need them to be on 1 line

Comment: Have you opened the browser web debugger and hovered over the elements with your mouse? That way you can see which element is taking up how much space and other useful things.

Comment: i do see that my logo is taking up all the space. but how do i make that smaller?https://imgur.com/a/ixbdysz

Comment: You have to decrease it by changing the "width" attribute of the CSS class. Try to see if other imported CSS libraries are globally changing widths for the logo element. I suspect that is what is not allowing you to change it. Otherwise specifically state the width attribute along with the HTML element as inline CSS (that has the highest precedence I believe).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jnA0MV9 close but not yet there